# Deploying web scraping website with selenium chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-deployment

I have created a website that scrapes multiple hockey websites for game scores. It runs perfectly on my local server and I am now in the process of trying to deploy. I have tried using pythonanywhere.com but selenium does not seem to be working on it. For any one who has deployed a website that uses selenium/webdriver, what is the easiest/best platform to deploy a website like this (it does not have to be free like pythonanywhere, as long as it is not too expensive, lol!). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS, GCP, or Digitalocean Linux servers. In this case, you first have to install chrome in Linux and then put the relevant version of the chrome driver in your project directory. Make sure to check the chrome version first and then put the relevant Chrome driver on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does work on PythonAnywhere. If you use a free account, you'd have restricted internet access though. Also it's recommended to scrape outside of the web app, since it would slow the views down -- you should rather use a Schedule/Always-on task for that instead. You can also refer to those PythonAnywhere help pages:

- [Using Selenium](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/)
- [Async work in web apps](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps/)